# Product should not visible to one profile

Tags: apex, administration

I have list of products in product object. So, for one profile I want to restrict to view one product(one product record) among list of products.

Comment: You cannot using profiles. You will need to setup roles, groups, sharing settings accordingly to be able to restrict visibility to records.

Comment: But Roles,groups,Sharing settings will give the visiblity or access to records but not restrict it right?

Comment: Record restriction starts with setting up the correct OWD in Sharing Settings. What you will need here is kind of a criteria based sharing rule to share only specific to say particular User/Group.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't set sharing on the Products object, the best way here is to:

- Create different Pricebooks in which one contains all the products and the other leaves out the products you don't want to expose to certain users
- Share these Pricebook with different
  users / groups.

Different profiles won't help you out as they only allow for general access and view all / modify all. They don't allow to differentiate record access the way you want.